# Specified cast is not valid (byte database, GetBytes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, casting

I'm thoroughly stumped by this cast conversion refusal.

Basically, I'm trying to retrieve data from a database and store it into a list - it worked fine until the **image** part.

The error kept saying it's type conversion error, but I have no idea how to correct the casting. T-T

Here's the snippet code of it:

List student = new List();

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ItemUpload"].ConnectionString);
        string selectQuery = "select * from upload";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);

        SqlDataReader dr;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                student.Add(new Item()
                {
                    ID = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                    itemImage = dr.GetByte(dr.GetOrdinal("itemname")),
                    itemName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("itemname")),
                    itemDesc = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("itemdesc")),
                    itemQuantity = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("qituantity"))
                });

            }
            dr.Close();
        }
```

And this is the getter and setter for itemimage (in a seperate class called Item), if it helps.

public byte itemImage { get; set; }

I've tried Convert.ToByte but it doesn't work, sadly. It's like I'm the gates to where the solution is, but it's out of my grasp.

I'm pretty sure that Getordinal returns as a Int from what I've searched, but I have no idea how to resolve the casting from thence.

Appreciate your help on this!

-very, sad guy

Comment: to add on, i did a typo above: I'm aware of the double "itemname", it should be:

dr.GetByte(dr.GetOrdinal("itemimage"))

instead, >->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
student.Add(new Item()
                {
                    ID = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                    itemImage = (byte)dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("itemimage")),
                    itemName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("itemname")),
                    itemDesc = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("itemdesc")),
                    itemQuantity = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("qituantity"))
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I went on into a different route already however, but still, i appreciate ur response on this!